# Expand Postgresql Nested Array Json Field

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table (log_table) and in this table there is a nested array json field (activities). With using this activities field, I want to normalize my row.

log_table:

```
- id:long
- activities:json
- date:timestamp
```

example activities field:

```
[ 
   { 
      "actionType":"NOTIFICATION",
      "items":null
   },
   { 
      "actionType":"MUTATION",
      "items":[ 
         { 
            "id":387015007,
            "name":"epic",
            "value":{ 
               "currency":"USD",
               "amount":1.76
            }
         },
         { 
            "id":386521039,
            "name":"test",
            "value":{ 
               "currency":"USD",
               "amount":1.76
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

As query, I've tried:

```
select 
* 
from 
log_table l, 
json_array_elements(l.activities) elems,
json_array_elements(elems->'items') obj;
```

With this query, I got error like below:

```
ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar
```

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of `items` should be marked as `[null]`, not `null`. You can use the case expression to correct this, e.g.:

```
select elems->>'actionType' as action_type, obj
from log_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(l.activities::jsonb) elems
cross join jsonb_array_elements(case elems->'items' when 'null' then '[null]' else elems->'items' end) obj

 action_type  |                                       obj
--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 NOTIFICATION | null
 MUTATION     | {"id": 387015007, "name": "epic", "value": {"amount": 1.76, "currency": "USD"}}
 MUTATION     | {"id": 386521039, "name": "test", "value": {"amount": 1.76, "currency": "USD"}}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I also wonder something about it. How can I create index for `log->activities->actionTypes->id` in here.

Comment: There is no type of index that you could use here.